# NuGet Pack providing Inconsistent Results when using csproj file

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I'm creating nupkg files from csproj files using the following command:

```
nuget pack pathToMy.csproj
```

When I perform this command against one of my csproj files the nupkg contains all of the dependencies and all of the assemblies for my project references.  However, when I run the same command against a csproj file in another solution I **only** get the dependencies.  I don't get any  my project referenced assemblies.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: You'll probably need to provide more details in order to reproduce the issue. I recommend posting detailed instructions that consistently reproduce the issue with the minimal # of steps to the NuGet discussion board. http://nuget.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic

Comment: +1 I'm experiencing a similar problem, only all of my dependencies project or package are missed. Did you ever enter an issue for this problem? I'd be interested to see...

Answer (score 0):

Did you remember to build the project first? If you haven't compiled the project, then NuGet pack won't pick up the project output.

You can also try:

```
nuget pack pathToMy.csproj -Build
```

That will cause NuGet to build your project first.